# Printing issue when iterating over lists

Tags: python, loops, printing, python-2.7

I'm iterating over a couple of lists and I have this printed output:

```
John, 17, 1.79
John, 19, 1.83
John, 21, 1.85
Tom, 16, 1.77
Tom, 20, 1.79
Tom, 21, 1.79
```

Just for clarification, it's: name, age and height. It prints everything on a new line.

The effect I want to achieve is this:

```
John, 17, 1.79, 19, 1.83, 21, 1.85
Tom, 16, 1.77, 20, 1.79, 21, 1.79
```

Generally the code is pretty complex (I got lost a tiny bit) that's why I'm not giving any more details how I'm iterating over my lists etc.  I hope this is enough for you guys to see the big picture and maybe come up with a working solution.

I think one possibility is to create an array for every name but I'm not too eager for this fix since, with a lot of names I have, it will not be too efficient I guess.

Sorry again, I gave this little details.

Comment: You can put a comma after the print statement to avoid a newline.

Comment: Can you show us what the lists actually looks like or at least the loop that you used to print the results that you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering you've list of lists you can use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and some [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec).

Note that if the names are not grouped together then you need to sort the list first:

```
In [98]: from itertools import groupby

In [99]: lis=[['John', 17, 1.79],
['John', 19, 1.83],
['John', 21, 1.85],
['Tom', 16, 1.77],
['Tom', 20, 1.79],
['Tom', 21, 1.79]]


>>> for k,v in groupby(lis,key=lambda x:x[0]):
       strs=", ".join(", ".join(map(str,x[1:] ) )  for x in v)
       print "{0}, {1}".format(k,strs)
...     
John, 17, 1.79, 19, 1.83, 21, 1.85
Tom, 16, 1.77, 20, 1.79, 21, 1.79
```

Comment: This is the solution I was thinking in my head as well...I was just hoping OP would give us the initial list(s) so we could formalize it a little better.  Oh well.  +1

Comment: @ Ashwini Chaudhary, Hi, thank you for working solution. One question please, do you know how to fix the code so that it prints all commas, like this `John, 17, 1.79, 19, 1.83, 21, 1.85` because the code of yours skips some commas.

Comment: @nutship for your sample input my code is not missing any commas.

Comment: I mean the code is not printing all the commes in places where needed. `John, 17, 1.7919, 1.8321, 1.85` I mean the commas between `1.7919` for example. It should be `1.79, 19`

Comment: @nutship ah! yes I missed that, see my updated solution.

Comment: Thank you again for caring about my comment and updating the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I could guess from your problem:

```
name_list = ['John', 'Tom']

for element in your_list:
    for name in name_list:
        if element == name:
            print("\n%s" % element)
        else:
            print(element, end=' ')
```

Comment: @ThijsvanDien Thanks for pointing out! I changed the code which does not do any such thingys anymore... :)

Comment: Well, I don't think this code does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I changed the code now, so have a look.

Comment: Try it using the Ashwini's demonstration above (`lis=...`). The `name_list` shouldn't even be necessary, but regardless of that, the output is far from what it should be.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the direction. I'm not too much advanced yet.